# Batch Downloader- Flash, Java, Air?

Tags: java, flash, store

I have a store that I maintain and we sell CD's.  When customers purchase an album, they have to go through and then click to download each and every song (zipping the files is not an option).  Needless to say, this is a pain.

Does anyone know of a solution to use iTunes-style downloading (will download a few at a time, and once those are done, new downloads start).  It would be great if people don't have to install anything, but if they do, that is ok.

Comment: I'm pretty sure superusers will suggest ton's of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sun offers a product called "[Sun Download Manager](http://www.sun.com/download/sdm/sdm_features.xml)", which they use for some of their products. You check out some products on their site you want to download for and after that you are downloading them all via the webstart enabled Download Manager. But it looks a bit, hmm, too business like. But all you need is a JRE installed which nearly anybody has. You can try it [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html).